# How to get a logic app to stop running after a successful run each day

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app that I want to run once a line item appears in a table each day. once that line item appear, i don't want the logic app to run anymore that day.  Can't quite think of how to accomplish this.

Comment: Do the trigger conditions not help you?

Comment: If that doesn't help you, you can always look at using the REST API's to disable the job after it's first successful run for the day and then enable it again via another job that runs at midnight in your timezone.

Comment: Sounds like you have a table trigger (sql server, sharepoint or some other data storage) and the trigger fires once that table receive an update or insert. Is that right? if you want to run that once, do you need to run as soon the line item appears? could be a scheduled run to run once a day on a fixed time?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using the related triggers you can use `Terminate` action to stop the flow.

After using `Get entities (V2)` I'm trying to Parse the result to get the timestamp of that particular entity to check if the table has an added row or not for that day

[image]

After parsing below is the condition that I'm using

```
{
"contains": [
"@formatDateTime(body('Parse_JSON')?[0]?['Timestamp'],'dd-MM-yyyy')",
"@formatDateTime(utcNow(),'dd-MM-yyyy')"]
}
```

Below is the complete flow of my Logic App

[image]

***RESULTS:***

[image]

To reproduce the same in your Logic App you can use the below code view

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Condition": {
                "actions": {
                    "Terminate": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "runStatus": "Succeeded"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "Terminate"
                    }
                },
                "else": {
                    "actions": {
                        "Delay": {
                            "inputs": {
                                "interval": {
                                    "count": 2,
                                    "unit": "Hour"
                                }
                            },
                            "runAfter": {},
                            "type": "wait"
                        },
                        "HTTP": {
                            "inputs": {
                                "method": "POST",
                                "uri": "<URI>"
                            },
                            "runAfter": {
                                "Delay": [
                                    "Succeeded"
                                ]
                            },
                            "type": "Http"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "expression": {
                    "and": [
                        {
                            "contains": [
                                "@formatDateTime(body('Parse_JSON')?[0]?['Timestamp'],'dd-MM-yyyy')",
                                "@formatDateTime(utcNow(),'dd-MM-yyyy')"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "If"
            },
            "Get_entities_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azuretables']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/storageAccounts/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/tables/@{encodeURIComponent('<TableName>')}/entities"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@body('Get_entities_(V2)')?['value']",
                    "schema": {
                        "items": {
                            "properties": {
                                "FirstName": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "LastName": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "PartitionKey": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "RowKey": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "Timestamp": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "odata.etag": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            },
                            "required": [
                                "odata.etag",
                                "PartitionKey",
                                "RowKey",
                                "Timestamp",
                                "FirstName",
                                "LastName"
                            ],
                            "type": "object"
                        },
                        "type": "array"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Get_entities_(V2)": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "azuretables": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<SUB_ID>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azuretables",
                    "connectionName": "azuretables",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<SUB_ID>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/azuretables"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use Recurrence trigger to trigger it in regular intervals with the same logic.